# Joomla plugin to override table prefix

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, prefix

**Overview:**
I have a single Joomla website that have various copies of the database tables all in the same database, but with different table prefixes.

Depending on which user is accessing the site, i need to alter which joomla table prefix is used in order to display the relevant tables.

This has to be site wide.

**Problem:**
with a core code hack i can alter the prefix as needed, but would prefer this as a plugin.

With the plugin i can get the prefix, using $db->getPrefix(), and i can set an immediate instance of the connection using $db = JDatabaseDriver::getInstance( $option ). But this is not site wide and is overwritten by the standard $db = JFactory::getDbo().

So i need a system plugin that will repalce every instance of a table prefix as it is run.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think that's a really cool idea -- but the people you want to answer it are probably on the joomla.stackexchange.com [joomla.se] site.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but if you install a new component or module you have many problem to synchronize this changes on all DB. I think the best for you is to redirect each user to his real site (many joomla file with many db).
Otherwise you can create a personal component and read table prefix of that user and display only date that you want, in this way just duplicate the tables you need and not all the joomla structure.